# Core Data migration fails for to-one relationship

Tags: objective-c, core-data, core-data-migration

I have the following model:

[image: Model Version 1]

`parent` is a to-one relationship (optional, no minimum, maximum=1).
`children` is the inverse to-many relationship (optional, no minimum, no maximum).

I added a new model version, where only the Entity `Room` is renamed to `Classroom`, all other entities are unchanged:

[image: Model Version 2]

I also created a mapping model for the migration, but the migration fails with the error message

```
reason = "Can't find mapping model for migration";
```

The strange thing is that if the `parent` relationship is created with minimum=1 (instead of no minimum) then the migration works without problems.

The persistent store is opened with the options

```
NSDictionary *options = @{NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption:@YES, NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption:@NO};
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a mapping model? You should avoid these complexities and simply use **Lightweight Migration** as explained in Apple's [Lightweight Migration Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmLightweightMigration.html).

Comment: The model is a reduced example of my actual model, which is more complicated and has more changes which don't work with lightweight migration. I just tried to reduce the problem as far as possible

Comment: Then your info about the model change is misleading. Please post the change that you need custom migration for.